# WEB API And MVC Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, oauth, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am using MVC controllers and Odata WEB API in my Web Application. I use AngularJS framework to communicate with odata APIs. However, As with time my application had to communicate with external applications, I configured a token server to authorize all API requests.
Token Server in Startup.Auth.cs

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/AccountControllerApi/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
```

And Following code in WebConfig

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

But now when I sends request from my authorized MVC pages to odata APIs, it denies all requests as unauthorized. But external applications can communicate easily with Token.

Could anyone suggest a solution for this problem. P.S. It is a multipage application.

Comment: As the question is a little bit confuse me, I want to check some info with you. You use OAuth before access OData server, which is built by WebAPI. And the OAuth server is setup by yourself. So in my opinion, the request you sent to OData server should contains token in header, which is generated your OAuth server with valid account/password/clientid etc... Your OData serve receive the request with token. Then call OAuth service to do the auth with token... does my understanding right?